# how to invalidate uiview constraints

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios6, nslayoutconstraint

I would like to invalidate a uiview constraints from code to force all fields to relayout based on a specific change in the view.

For example, suppose i have two UILabels that are given a fixed VerticalSpace constraint. And in some user event i am resizing the label that is on top. I would like to be able to force the constraint to invalidate from code.

This is the first time i use constraints and i do not understand how i can do this from code. I know that when the device is rotated constraints on UIViews are invalidated.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You call `setNeedsLayout` on the relevant view, typically your view controller's `.view`. :

```
[self.view setNeedsLayout];
```

You're not really invalidating the constraints, that is a slightly different thing used for custom views which may need to remove and recalculate constraints based on other changes. What you're doing is letting the view know that some of the factors it used to calculate its layout have now changed. The constraints are still valid, but the results have changed.

To animate to your new layout, you can call `layoutIfNeeded` inside an animation block.

Comment: if i call
    [self.view setNeedsLayout];
the label does not change frame nor does the constraint change in result.

Comment: Self.view was only an example. You haven't said how your views are laid out or where anything is, or what you are changing.

Comment: For example, if your layout is created by constraints, you can't resize views by setting frames. You have to change the constant of one of the sizing constraints instead, otherwise a layout pass will simply revert to your constrained layout.

Comment: Thank you for your help jrturton. I now understand how to use the constraints. But suppose i have the following situation how would you recommend i do this.
I have the top element a UITextView with dynamic text. And in some events of the application i change the text and i would like to call sizeToFit or any equivalent method with constraints. And as a result i want the view below, which i set the VerticalSpace Constraint on between these 2 views, to reposition itself after the UITextView changes size.

Comment: I was playing around with the code and i accidentally figured it out. Setting the constraint relation to GreaterThanOrEqual does reproduce the effect i asked about in my previous comment.